# Using foreach to submit a dynamically generated form

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, foreach

I've created a dynamically generated form for the purpose of allowing users to record project milestones. Users can input the date and a description of the milestone, and then gives an option to add a row to record another (see this image for clarification: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/milestones_ex.png).  I am, however having trouble saving this to a database (I'm a sooper-noob on matters of php).

The form is generated with the following function:

```
function create_milestones_form() {
    global $wpdb;

    $inc = array(
        'yes' => ($data['incorporated']==1)?'checked="checked"':'',
        'no' => ($data['incorporated']!=1)?'checked="checked"':'',
    );

    $site = array(
        'yes' => ($data['has']==1)?'checked="checked"':'',
        'no' => ($data['incorporated']!=1)?'checked="checked"':'',
    );

    return <<<EOHTML
    <form method='post'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://upsmart.com/wp-content/plugins/upsmart_sitemanager/js/create_business_milestone.js"></script>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />


    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
        <TD>
        <select name="month">
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="day">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select name="year">
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
        </select>
        </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" name="txt"/> </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <input type='submit' value='Save'/>
    </form>
EOHTML;
}
```

Upon clicking save, it is (or should be) saved to the database using the following function:

```
function create_milestones_save() {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("REPLACE INTO upsmart_milestones
                                          (wordpress_id,month,day,year,description)
                                          VALUES(%d,%d,%d,%d,%s)",
                                          array(
                                              get_current_user_id(),
                                              $_POST['month'],
                                              $_POST['day'],
                                              $_POST['year'],
                                              $_POST['txt'],
                                          )
    ));

    if($result === false) return false;
    return true;
}
```

So the situation is this: with just one milestone, I can get it to save without a problem, however I cannot get it to save multiple milestones; this makes some sense sense as I'm not looping through any of the variables.  I'm guessing that I need to send each variable (month, day, year, and txt) to create_milestones_save() as an array, then use a foreach loop to store each entry in the database.  I'm just really unsure as to how I would code that in php.

Thanks a bunch in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs should be named month[], day[], year[] and txt[] just like the checkbox is chk[].
Then for example $_POST["month"] would be an array containing the months of all the milestones in order.
You should also give each of the checkboxes a unique value, for example an increasing number.

Then you can loop through them like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST["chk"] as $chk_value)
{

    $id = (int)$chk_value; // The position of the milestone in the form

    $day = $_POST["day"][$id];
    $month = $_POST["month"][$id];
    $year = $_POST["year"][$id];
    $txt = $_POST["txt"][$id];

    // Execute query with data in $day, $month, $year and $txt
}
?>
```

Please note that this loop will only loop through the milestones which were selected with a checkbox.

Comment: so would I need to do anything to $_POST["month"] to make it an array?  Or would simply changing month to month[] take care of that?

Comment: Yes, changing month to month[] will take care of that.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Might I be able to skip the check-box numbering if I used 'txt' as the key?  Basically I'm just using the check boxes for deletions.  It's fine with me to save all rows in the form that are visible.  How might I change the loop to accomplish this?

Comment: I thought the checkboxes were an on and off type thing. You can ofcourse execute the foreach loop on the txt[]. You could just have a counter instead of an ID number in the form:
`$i = 0;
foreach ($_POST["txt"] as $txt_value)
{
$txt = $txt_value;
$day = $_POST["day"][$i];
$i++;
}`

Comment: Jesbus, thanks so much for your help.  I feel like I'm really close to getting it to work but I must be missing something, as it just won't go through.  You've already been wonderfully patient but I was wondering if you could have a look at my code if you have a moment.  I've copied the function in question into the following text file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/Sam_adventures_in_PHP.txt

Comment: Thanks for the overview, please try an `echo mysql_error();` after executing the query, maybe we're overlooking something there.

Comment: Also, the month is 0 because you're requesting it with $_post instead of $_POST, and you're quitting the foreach loop with a return. You're also missing the `$i++;` at the bottom of the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for catching both of those.  I also figured out there were two other problems with help from your advice to add the echo mysql_error().  One is that I was putting the return statement inside the foreach loop (brilliant, right?) and then found that I was using the user id as my primary key in the database, meaning that it wouldn't write once it had a single entry for the given user.  When I changed those, it worked perfectly.  Thanks SO much!